# lost messages on zeromq pub sub

Tags: c++, publish-subscribe, zeromq

I'm trying to implement the pub sub design pattern using zeromq framework.
The idea is to launch a subscriber and afterwards to launch the publisher.
The subscriber will listen to 100 messages and the publisher will publish 100 messages.
So far so good...
However what actually happens is that even that the subscriber is already up and running when the publisher is launched , not all of the messages are received by the subscriber (a 100 messages will be picked up by the subscriber if the publisher will send at least 500 message). It seems that the first messages sent by the publisher are not sent to the subscriber.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Omer.

***Subscriber code (launched before the publisher)***

```
int i=0;
zmq::context_t context (1);
zmq::socket_t subscriber (context, ZMQ_SUB);
subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:5556");
subscriber.setsockopt(ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);

for (int update_nbr = 0; update_nbr < 100; update_nbr++) 
{        
    zmq::message_t update;
    subscriber.recv(&update);
    i++;
    std::cout<<"receiving  :"<<i<<std::endl;
}
```

***Publisher code (launched after the subscriber)***

```
zmq::context_t context (1);
zmq::socket_t publisher (context, ZMQ_PUB);
publisher.bind("tcp://*:5556");

int i = 0;
for (int update_nbr = 0; update_nbr < 100; update_nbr++) 
{        
    //  Send message to all subscribers
    zmq::message_t request (20);

    time_t seconds;
    seconds = time (NULL);

    char update [20]="";
    sprintf (update, "%ld", seconds);

    memcpy ((void *) request.data (), update,strlen(update));
    publisher.send(request);
    i++;
    std::cout << "sending :" << i << std::endl;
```

}

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/#Missing-Message-Problem-Solver (flowchart in Figure 25, and explanations below)

Basically, it takes a little time (a few milliseconds) for the connection to be set up, and in that time lots of messages can be lost. The publisher needs to sleep a little before starting to publish, or (better) it needs to explicitly synchronize with the subscriber.

Comment: I would suggest going with the synchronization of subs with the pub vs a straight forward sleep... You never really know how long you should wait (esp if you have remote subs) but with explicit sync (through a req/rep socket is a good way) you do not have to worry about guessing...

Comment: link broken, new link: https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter1/

Comment: new link https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/#Missing-Message-Problem-Solver

Answer (score 3):

Please look the [guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Node-Coordination).

1. publisher sends "hello"
2. each subscriber that receive "hello", send a message to publisher via REQ/REP socket
3. when publisher gets enough REQ/REP message, then it begins to publish data

Answer (score 2):

In 0MQ, successful send() does not mean that data is sent immediately over network. http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-send. Your messages are pretty small, and AFAIR 0MQ does some sort of buffering for small messages to use network more effectively.

If I remember correctly , `out_batch_size` in `config.hpp` of 0MQ controls such behavior.

Comment: But that doesn't explain the first few messages going missing.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to look at (beyond what previous commenters have noted) is your shutdown procedure.

The code snippets might simply be incomplete, but I don't see how you are handling shutdown.  In particular you might actually be losing the *last* messages that are sent.  Take a look at the documentation for **zmq_close**, **zmq_term** and **ZMQ_LINGER**.  If you are *not* actually calling these functions and instead are simply terminating the application, then there is a chance that the messages that have been sent with **zmq_send()** but haven't been transferred to the network are being lost at shutdown.

To check which messages are being lost, you might try to send a sequence number in addition to the timestamp.